# usage of or operator in python

Tags: python, or-operator

Please explain what is going on with the or operator here in python

```py
>>>sen='abcdef'
>>>'a' in sen
True
>>>'v' or 'z' in sen
'v'
>>>('v' or 'z') in sen
False
>>>('v' or 'a') in sen
False
>>>('a' or 'v') in sen
True
```

The first output obviously makes sense. From the second output, I do not follow what is going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the parenthesis, you tell the interpreter to interpret what's inside the parenthesis first. So let's go over the outputs, starting from the second one:

```py
>>>('v' or 'z') in sen
```

What you did here is:
`('v' or 'z')` translates to `v` because it goes from left to right - They both evaluate to `True`, so if you would to write `'z' or 'v'` it would evaluate to `z`. So you are checking if `v` is inside `sen` --> `False`.

Moving on:

```py
>>>('v' or 'a') in sen --> is 'v' inside sen?
False
>>>('a' or 'v') in sen --> is 'a' inside sen?
True
```